# Invoke MethodInfo from dll file

Tags: .net, vb.net, invoke, gettype, methodinfo

I'm writing a dll library that must be attachable to any project, and there's one thing I cannot resolve.

I need to Invoke/Run MethodInfo from dll file. And it looks something like this.
SenderMethod, the same as args and there count is dynamic.

```
Private Shared Sub BGthread(SenderMethod As MethodInfo, arg0 As Object, arg1 As Object, ...)
    Dim SenderType As Type = GetType(SenderMethod.ReflectedType.Name)
    SenderMethod.Invoke(SenderType, New Object() {ActLV, e, Arg0, Arg1, ...})
End Sub
```

The problem is that GetType returns nothing. I know the assambly name is missing there, but I have failed to find a solution applyable to situation that caller class is not static.

Please help!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`SenderMethod.ReflectedType.AssemblyQualifiedName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx) in your call to `GetType`.

Comment: Thank you for replay! Now i got `Dim SenderType As Type = SenderMethod.ReflectedType.AssemblyQualifiedName.GetType` and `SenderMethod.Invoke(SenderType, New Object() {ActLV, e})` that gives error: TargetExpension was Unhandled - Object does not match target type. I believe this is because SenderType is System.String :/ What am I missing?

Comment: The first parameter to `MethodInfo.Invoke` has to be an instance of the type `SenderType`. It would be best if you just would pass that into you method as well.